# Maximally spaced small circles inside large circle

Tags: geometry

Given a circle of diameter $D$, and $N$ smaller circles of diameter $d$ < $D$, find the optimum arrangement of small circles inside the big circle, such that the small circles are as far away as possible from each other and from the edge of the large circle.

Comment: Questions asked *without any effort/attempt* to find a solution are poorly received on this website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the problem if you set the distance between the center of each of the small circles and the edge of the big circle equal to the distance between two centers of two small circle, where the centers of the small circles are assumed to lie on a regular polygon of $N$ sides.

If the radius of this polygon is $R$ then, the above statement means

$ D - R = 2 R \sin \left( \dfrac{\pi}{N} \right) $

so that

$R = \dfrac{ D }{ 1 + 2 \sin \left( \dfrac{\pi}{N} \right) }$